Discrepancy between Pages and Countries table (Google Search Console)
Summary
Analysing the clicks and impressions measured in Google Search Console for the following page:

Separation Anxiety in Dogs at Pet Coach SG

Objective
To understand the number of clicks and impressions from Singapore to specific pages in my website.
Steps Taken

Access the Google Search Console Property
In the Pages tab, click into the Separation Anxiety Page URL. This filters for clicks and impressions for the Separation Anxiety Page

Discrepancy in Pages vs Countries Query
The results are as follows:

Pages tab has 22 clicks and 211 impressions  
Countries tab has 1 click and 51 impressions 

Clarification
Would someone be able to advise how we can interpret this data? 
Do let me know if there is further information required.
Thank you.
Additional Information
Google has highlighted that there can be discrepancies between the charts and the table. But I could not find any information that highlights the discrepancies between two tables (Pages and Countries table).
My understanding is as such:

The Pages table is aggregated based on the specific page (URL)
The Countries table is aggregated based on the property (a.k.a. the whole site)

However, unable to wrap my head around:

Why is there only 51 impressions when aggregating by site?
But there is 211 impressions when aggregating by page?

Wouldn't each page impression, also translate to a site impression?
